# Running Laravel Jobs/Handling Events in Order Received

Tags: laravel, events, webhooks, jobs, endpoint

I have an endpoint: /webhook/events

I'll receive events from a 3rd-party rapidly to this endpoint like below that contains the order information.

> Order: Update (4s to process)
> Order: Delete (3s to process)

What happens is that when I receive these events, I check to see if the order exists. If the order exists in our DB and it's been soft-deleted, I restore it. In the 3rd-party application, an order can be deleted and restored so I have to reflect this functionality.

My problem is that I may get both of the events above within milliseconds of each other, so in this case, the Update Order/Delete event finishes followed by the Update Order event. This soft-deletes the order, then restores it.

I need to make sure that the events run consecutively instead of racing, but I'm not sure how.

Comment: Take a look at: https://laravel.com/docs/7.x/queries#pessimistic-locking

Comment: That might be what I'm looking for. I'm researching now, but do you know if I were to use pessimistic locking, would consecutive events queue up while locked, or would they just be skipped?

Comment: Not an expert on this matter, but to my knowledge, they will be queued.

Comment: I was wrong, the locks are implemented in \Illuminate\Cache\DatabaseLock